# Trigger compilation error reasons

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, compiler-errors

Hi guys I have two triggers I am meant to be be creating but I am getting compilation errors on both

this first is supposed to record evaluations of 0 to an audit table and the second is supposed to prevent the deletion of entries in which the date is less than todays date.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE EVALUATION_AUDIT
2  (C_NAME VARCHAR (15), CO_ID NUMBER(7), E_DATE DATE,
3  V_ID NUMBER (7), C_EVALUATION NUMBER(1));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ZERO_EVAL
 2  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF C_EVALUATION ON CUSTOMER_EVENT
 3  FOR EACH ROW
 4  WHEN (NEW.C_EVALUATION = 0)
 5  BEGIN
 6  SELECT C_NAME, CO_ID, E_DATE, V_ID, C_EVALUATION
 7  FROM CUSTOMER_EVENT CE, CUSTOMER C, EVENT E
 8  WHERE CE.C_ID = C.C_ID
 9  AND CE.EVENT_ID = E.EVENT_ID
10  AND C_EVALUATION = NEW.C_EVALUATION;
11  INSERT INTO EVALUATION AUDIT
12  VALUES (:NEW.C_NAME, :NEW.CO_ID, :NEW.E_DATE, :NEW.V_ID, :NEW.C_EVALUATION);
13  END;
14  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.


SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PASTEVENTS
  2  BEFORE DELETE
  3  ON EVENT
  4  FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6  IF :OLD.E_DATE =< SYSDATE
  7  THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20002, 'CAN NOT DELETE PAST EVENT RECORDS');
  8  
  9  END IF;
 10  END;
 11  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

Comment: When you see that there are errors, type "show errors" to get a listing of the specific errors.

Answer (score 1):

As Justin said, when you get `created with compilation errors` for any stored PL/SQL, type `show errors`, or you can query the `user_errors` table to see all outstanding errors on your objects.

From a quick scan, the first trigger is missing a colon when you reference `NEW.C_EVALUATION` in the select:

```
AND C_EVALUATION = :NEW.C_EVALUATION;
```

You need to select into something, though I'm not sure if it's necessary here as you have the values from the `:NEW` psuedorecord; not sure why you're selecting at all?

And the second has an incorrect operator, `=<` instead of `<=`:

```
IF :OLD.E_DATE <= SYSDATE
```

It's generally a good idea to prefix column names with the table alias to avoid ambiguity, e.g. `SELECT C.C_NAME, ...` if that column comes from the `CUSTOMER` table, etc. You could have another error in there is you have the same column on multiple tables. And it's good practise to list the column names in your `INSERT` too, i.e. `INSERT INTO EVALUATION_AUDIT (C_NAME, ...) VALUES (...)`. With the missing underscore that @Dba spotted!

Answer (score 1):

In your first trigger code you don't need to `SELECT` from the tables as you are just inserting the values from the table `CUSTOMET_EVENT` to `EVALUATION_AUDIT`. Also you have missed and underscore `_` in table_name in `EVALUATION_AUDIT` in line 11.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER zero_eval
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF c_evaluation ON customer_event
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.c_evaluation = 0)
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO evaluation_audit(c_name, co_id, e_date, v_id, c_evaluation)
     VALUES (:NEW.c_name, :NEW.co_id, :NEW.e_date, :NEW.v_id, :NEW.c_evaluation);
END;
/
```

In Your second code, it should be `<=` instead of `=<`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pastevents
BEFORE DELETE
ON event
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF :OLD.e_date <= SYSDATE THEN 
          raise_application_error (-20002, 'CAN NOT DELETE PAST EVENT RECORDS');
     END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: when I type in the code like that, I get an error saying bad bind variable for the first one

Comment: @JohnSmith, make sure the columns c_name, co_id, e_date, v_id, c_evaluation are there in customer_event table.

Comment: they arent all in customer_event they are across multiple tables :S